# Merging PDFs skipping corrupted PDFs

Tags: ghostscript, pdftk

Currently I am using Ghostscript to merge a list of PDFs which are downloaded. The issue is if any 1 of the pdf is corrupted, it stops the merging of the rest of the pdfs.

Is there any command which i must use so that it will skip the corrupted pdfs and merge the others?

I have also tested with pdftk but facing the same issue.

Or is there any other command line based pdf merging utility that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try MuPDF, you could also try using MUPDF 'clean' to repair files before you try merging them. However if the PDF file is so badly corrupted that Ghostscript can't even repair it that probably won't work either.

There is no facility to ignore PDF files which are so badly corrupted they can't even be repaired. Its hard to see how this could work in the current scheme, since Ghostscript doesn't 'merge' files anyway, it interprets them, creating a brand new PDF file from the sequence of graphic operations. When a file is badly enough corrupted to provoke an error we abort because we may have already written any parts of the file we could, and if we tried to ignore and continue both the interpreter and the output PDF file would be in an indeterminate state.